# why zenity doesn't work with udev script?

Tags: linux, udev

i make this udev rule to ask me everytime i plug in a usb device if i want to authorize it

> 80-block-usb.rules
>
> `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-check.sh $env{DEVPATH}"`

> usb-check.sh
>
> ````bash
> #!/bin/bash
>
> devpath="$1" name="$2" export DISPLAY=:1
>
> echo $devpath /bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys'${devpath}'/authorized'
> zenity --question --text='Do you want to authorize "'$name'"?' && /bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys'${devpath}'/authorized' ```
> ````

when i plug in a device it doesn't get authorized (that's good) but there isn't the zenity popup

Comment: separate the "steps" with `;`s. i.e. `'echo 0 > /sys'${devpath}'/authorized' ; zenity ..... ; echo ....` . A very nice bit of useful code (I think). Let us know if this fixes it and that it now works are required. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it doesn't work :/

Comment: Too much crap getting installed to test with zenity )-; ... I pretty sure you have a major prroblem with `echo`, notice what results you get if you enter `echo "my/dev/path"  /bin/sh -c 'pwd'` . Recommend you put each significant statement-group onto it's own line, using continuation char `"\"` (just the backslash) to make your code more readable (and testable). I'm busy today, but will check back later. Good luck.